# Given numbers from $1$ to $N$, find the number of arrangements in which $a$ comes before $b$

Tags: combinatorics

We have $N$ numbers from $1$ to $N$. What is the number of arrangements in which number $a$ appears before number $b$?

My solution:

I keep number $a$ fixed at one location, and find the number of ways to fill the locations before $a$ and after $a$.

So the formula I got is:

$(n-1)! + (n-2)((n-2)!) + (n-2)(n-3)((n-3)!) + (n-2)(n-3)(n-4)((n-4)!) + ...$

Is there a closed formula to solve this problem? Also, is my approach correct?

Answer (score 2):

Well, either $a$ is before $b$,  or $a$ is after $b$,  and the two situations are arbitrary, nothing makes one more likely than the other.    You have $n!$ total arrangements,  therefore in half of them $a$ will be before $b$,  $\frac {n!} 2$

Comment: Ok, that was something I did not observe, thanks :)

What if there are multiple such constraints? Say a1 occurs before b1, a2 before b2, ... so on?

Comment: If $a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2$ are four distinct elements, then "$a_1$ before $b_1$" and "$a_2$ before $b_2$" are independent events, so they both occur in $1/4$ of the $n!$ arrangements. On the other hand, if $a,b,c$ are three distinct elements, then "$a$ before $b$ and $a$ before $c$" happens $1/3$ of the time, while "$a$ before $b$ and $b$ before $c$" happens $1/6$ of the time. Under the most general interpretation of the question in your comment, you're asking how many ways can a partial order on a finite set be extended to a linear order. That's a hard problem.

Answer (score 1):

Alan's solution is the neat way to solve this problem, but your approach is also correct. You have
$$(n-1)!+\sum_{k=2}^n(n-2)(n-3)\cdots(n-k)[(n-k)!]$$
$$=(n-1)!+\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{(n-2)!}{(n-k-1)!}\cdot(n-k)!$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(n-2)!}{(n-k-1)!}\cdot(n-k)!$$
$$=(n-2)!\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(n-k)!}{(n-k-1)!}$$
$$=(n-2)!\sum_{k=1}^n(n-k)$$
$$=(n-2)!\cdot\frac{n(n-1)}2$$
$$=\frac{n!}2.$$